# ConstraintLayout improper height adjustment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-constraintlayout

I thought I got a good hold over Constraint Layout. But this height issue is weird.

**Problem**

`ConstraintLayout` with `@id/boarding` takes full height between `@id/progress_layout` and `@id/take_off_button` rightly. But its children `@id/boarding_counter` and `@id/runway` are not taking entire height of the parent. I have defined proper attributes to children: `width:0dp`, `app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent",app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"`, still they only take partial random height.

**Please help**

Here is my layout file and I have also attached the screenshots:
[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:transitionName="@string/transition_send_to_clip_verification">


    <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/progress_layout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/boarding"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/progress1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="@dimen/padding_left_right"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/divider1"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <TextView
                    style="@style/text_12_bold_primary"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_send"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Check In"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/divider1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@color/text_primary"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/progress1"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/progress2"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"></View>

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/progress2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="@dimen/padding_left_right"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/divider1"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/divider2"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <TextView
                    style="@style/text_12_bold_primary"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_send"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Choose destination"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />


            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/divider2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@color/text_primary"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/progress2"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/progress3"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"></View>

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/progress3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="@dimen/padding_left_right"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/divider2"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <TextView
                    style="@style/text_12_bold_primary"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_send"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Take Off"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/boarding"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/take_off_button"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/progress_layout">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/boarding_counter"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHeight_default="spread"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/runway"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/runway"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHeight_default="spread"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/boarding_counter"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_road" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/taxis"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/take_off_button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/color_primary_bg"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding_top_bottom"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/boarding">

            <TextView
                style="@style/text_16_bold"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="TAKE OFF"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Update**

Changing the library version worked but temporarily. When I add item in Recycler View `@id/taxis`, the height again reduces to half.

Here is the video:

[image: Gif]

Comment: I just tried to recreate this with `1.0.2` and [this](https://imgur.com/a/vCwQ5) is what I got.

Comment: I a'int getting the same with 1.0.2. So I changed to 1.1.0-beta3. Now the height is changing when I'm changing the content. This is first time I have experienced such weird behavior with ConstraintLayout. It'll be of great help if you could provide me the dependency of older version than 1.0.0. I googled it, but couldn't find one.

Comment: Would you mind sharing your project so that I can have a look at the behavior? `ConstraintLayout` is supposed to get rid of nested views so I guess simplifying that might be of some help.

As for the version, I'm not sure here, but I think it started with `1.0.0-alpha1` so you wouldn't find an older version.

Answer (score 1):

Update to `ConstraintLayout` 1.1.0-beta3 to correct this problem:

```
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0-beta3'
```

If you can't update to this later, albeit beta version, post back for an alternate solution.

Comment: This did worked. Thank you! I was using 1.2.0 earlier. This is a bug in stable and latest version.

Comment: @PrinceBansal Isn't this a modified XML file? I am seeing that things have changed around a bit. `runway` was an image view but now is a constraint layout and `taxis` didn't appear at all.

Comment: Yes. I have enclosed it in ConstraintLayout. And it works same before and after enclosure. And I needed a recyclerview over image view so I included `taxis`.